# Get total of array items in mongodb where array is embedded into other property in the document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given this document

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "item" : "ABC1",
    "description" : "product 1",
    "test" : {
        "colors" : [ 
            "blue", 
            "black", 
            "red"
        ]
    }
}
```

how do you get total items in array `colors`? I have tried this

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {            
            numberOfColors: { $size: "test.$colors" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

but I got this error

```
Failed to execute script.

Error:
Assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String",
    "code" : 17124
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1

Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String",
    "code" : 17124
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {            
            numberOfColors: { $size: "$test.colors" }
         }
      }
   ]
)` More here on dot notation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your query from

```
numberOfColors: { $size: "test.$colors" }
```

to

```
numberOfColors: { $size: "$test.colors" }
```